# Finding a function $f(X,Y)$, such that $f(1,x) = f(x,1) = f(\ln x, \ln x)$

Tags: calculus

Can you help me find a function $f(X,Y)$, such that $f(1,x) = f(x,1) = f(\ln x, \ln x)$?

Either always, for all $x$ or in the limit $x$ tends to infinity, all these three expressions must become equal.
Actually in computer science, there are arrays in which update takes constant $O(1)$ time, and cumulative sum linear $O(n)$ time.

In cumulative arrays, update takes $O(n)$ time and sum is constant time.

While in segment trees, both are $O(\ln n)$

So I thought that there might be some $f(\text{update}, \text{sum}) = \text{constant function}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about
$$f(x,y)=(a_1,...,a_n)$$
For as many constants ($n$) as you'd like: $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\exp(\sqrt{(X-1)(Y-1)}+1)+|X-Y|$$
$f(x,1)=f(1,x)=x+e-1; f(\ln(x),\ln(x))=x$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(X,Y)=(X-1)(Y-1)(X-Y)$$
$f(x,1)=f(1,x)=f(\ln{x},\ln{x})=0$